# php jquery dialog submit - only works to close function on top result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, submit

I have a google books function that returns book titles from a user input to a search window. My jquery dialog window displays the results. Next to each result, a submit button appears. I want my user to be able to select one of the results and return the values associated with the title they select (published, author, cover, etc).

My window displays 10 results, but clicking on the top result (submit button) is the only one that closes the window. The other 9 buttons do not work.

Can someone please help me with this?

```
    if ($totalItems > 0) {
  ?>

      <!doctype html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//whosgotbooks.com/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css">
      <script src="//whosgotbooks.com/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//whosgotbooks.com/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="dialog" title="Google Books Search Results" style="display:none;">
      <script>
      $(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        height: 550, width: 450});
       $( "#returnvalues" ).click(function(){
       $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" ); 
       });
       });
      </script>     
            <strong><p style="font-size: 16px; text-align: center";>Top 10 Results for &quot;<?php echo @$_POST['q']; ?>&quot;</p></strong> 
        <strong><p style="font-size: 14px; text-align: center";>choose a book to select as your topic</p></strong>&nbsp;
        <table style="width:400px">
        <col width="325">
        <col width="75">
            <?php foreach ($data['items'] as $item) { ?>    
                  <tr>
            <td>
                       <strong><u><div style="font-size: 14px";><?php printf($item['volumeInfo']['title'])?></u></div></strong>
                         <strong>Author: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['authors'][0])?><br />
                         <strong>Published: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['publishedDate']); ?><br />                       
               <strong>Page(s): </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['pageCount']); ?><br />
                         <strong>Publisher: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['publisher']); ?><br />
                         <strong>Category: </strong><?php printf( strtolower($item['volumeInfo']['printType']).', '.strtolower($item['volumeInfo']['categories'][0])); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <strong>ISBN: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['identifier']); ?></td>
            <td><p><input type="submit" name="select" value="Select" id="returnvalues"/></p>
                <img src="<?php printf( rawurldecode($item['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail'])); ?>" />
                    </td>
            <tr><td style="width:420px"><p><strong>Description: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['description']); ?><br /></p></td>           
            </tr>
            </tr>

            <?php } }
            else {
                ?>
                   <p><strong>Sorry, there were no results</strong></p>
                <?php  } 
            /* for testing purposes show actual request to API - REMOVE when finished
            $apiRequest = $url;
            echo '<p>API request: '.$apiRequest.'</p>'; */ ?>
        </table>
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>

          <?php
          else: //show form and allow the user to check for Google Book search results
          ?>

      <p><form id="searchForm" name="searchForm" method="post"> 
        <fieldset id="searchBox">
            <label>Search for a Book:</label>
            <input class="text" id="q" name="q" type="text" value="Powered by Google" onfocus="this.value=''; this.onfocus=null;" />
            <select id="type" name="type" size="1">
                <option selected value="all">Book Title</option>
                <option value="isbn">Books by ISBN</option>
                <option value="lccn">Books by LCCN #</option>
                <option value="oclc">Books by OCLC #</option>                
            </select>
            <input class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Search"  />
        </fieldset>
      </form></p>
      <?php
      //end submit isset if statement on line 73
      endif;

      if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] )) {
//      echo "$title Test";
      global $author;
      $book_title=$item['volumeInfo']['title'];
      $author=$item['volumeInfo']['authors'][0];
      $published=$item['volumeInfo']['publishedDate'];
      $cover=rawurldecode($item['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail']);
      echo "$title '$book_title'<br>";
      echo "$title '$author'<br>";
      echo "$title '$published'<br>";
      echo "<img src=$title $cover><br>";
//      print_r($_POST);
      }
```

The input portion to create the "Select" button within the above code is:

```
<td><p><input type="submit" name="select" value="Select" id="returnvalues"/></p>
```

This code is within the loop that displays 10 results. As I mentioned, it only works to close the window on the first result displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same ID for all of the submit buttons - IDs should always be unique.  Your JQuery selector `$("#returnvalues")` will only apply to the first one it finds.

After giving each button a unique ID, you could give them all the same class and access them that way `$(".btn")`, or you can access them all as they are with `$("p>input")`

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3AaV/

Comment: thanks. I did what was in the link, except I did not change the id returnvalues. It is a while loop. I was going to try increment numbers, but I tried your code without doing that and it now works, so thanks. However, I might still have to increment numbers as I have to now figure out how to identify which one a user selects.